# Java Reflections: Get Classes but not SubTypes

Tags: java, reflection

I'm upgrading from org.reflections:reflections:0.9.5 to version 0.9.9. I am  using:

```
Reflections reflectionPaths = new Reflections("resources", new TypeAnnotationsScanner());
Set<Class<?>> rootResourceClasses = reflectionPaths.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Path.class);
```

Which gets me all classes in the `resources` package with an `@Path` Annotation.
Since the library has been updated the top line requires an extra `new SubTypesScanner()` for the code to run. I however do not want sub types to be returned.

How can I use this new version of the library to pull back only classes and interfaces that are not sub types?

---

I get this Exception if I don't include the SubTypesScanner

```
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: Scanner SubTypesScanner was not configured
    at org.reflections.Store.get(Store.java:58)
    at org.reflections.Store.get(Store.java:70)
    at org.reflections.Store.getAll(Store.java:97)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.getAllAnnotated(Reflections.java:423)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Reflections.java:384)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Reflections.java:370)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you using this annotation "javax.ws.rs.Path". Pls try this :-

```
Reflections reflectionPaths = new Reflections("resources", new TypeAnnotationsScanner());
Set<Class<?>> rootResourceClasses = reflectionPaths.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Path.class, true);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me :( and I still get the same error. The strange thing is for me I get `TypeAnnotationsScanner was not configured` while I have `new TypeAnnotationsScanner()` already there. Any idea why it's failing?

Comment: @xbmono any successon that topic. i have the same problem, scanner got passed in the constructor and telling me its not configured

Comment: @HenningLuther Sorry this was a long time ago and I really don't remember what I have done but in my case the same code worked fine (not sure if that was a bug in jdk and we upgraded it or something else) but this code works fine: `Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new String[]{"com.mypackage"});`

Comment: @xbmono thx for the answer. it seems i got this issue when using java13. somehow reflections doesnt work after upgrading from 8 to 13. so i just wait for them to deliver a fix for 13

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and my solution is providing SubTypesScanner as well:

```
Reflections reflectionPaths = new Reflections(packageString, 
                                    new TypeAnnotationsScanner(), new SubTypesScanner());
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but I had that `Scanner SubTypesScanner was not configured` error which started appearing when I updated a totally unrelated lib.

I found [that message](https://github.com/victools/jsonschema-generator/issues/102#issuecomment-640905754) where someone, looking for a similar error, discovered that the exception is thrown when the path is totally empty (not my case) but also if a base class of the one looked for is not in the scanned package (my case).

I have zero idea why it used to work, nor why it stopped, but I added the missing package in the scanner and it started working again.