# How to import library in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import

I want to use this [library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) in a Java project. How can i import this library and use it in my project?

I've heard about .jar files, that I should add. But this [library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) has no .jar in it, only source files. So I don't know what is the best/cleanest way to import and use this library.

If you need any more information to help, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: I'd suggest to use Maven (or Gradle) for that.

Comment: @AlexandruSomai Can we not use a library without Maven or anything else? Just in a simple way?

Comment: I've added an answer for how you can download the .jar file for your needed library.

Comment: @Axel dependency managers like Maven are designed to do the work for you, especially if you have multiple dependencies. You could potentially copy the files into your source tree but you need to check the license and attribute properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach for that would be to use Maven (or Gradle).

But, if you really want to download the .jar file and import that one into IntelliJ, you can download it from Maven Central, here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reflections/reflections/0.9.12.

[image]

Or, alternatively, just follow this link: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/reflections/reflections/0.9.12/ and get the .jar from there.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a maven project you can import the library by inserting the dependency entry of the library to the `dependencies` like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```

If you don't have a `pom.xml`, you can insert the .jar through Intellij. Everything that is deployed to the Maven Central Repository has a `.jar` produced.

So you can go to the project structure by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and on the `Modules` menu on the left you can press the `+` icon and then select `from Maven...`. On the field of the pop up you can insert the name of the library, search for it, and then press `OK`.

If you want to import it manually (not recommended) you can download the `.jar` directly from the Maven Central Repository [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reflections/reflections/0.9.12). When you download it you just go to the project structure like before and you just select `Java` instead of `from maven`.

Comment: This is not a maven project. As it is a really small project, it is a basic java project, with only few files in a package.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can do it

1. if you have a maven project. Add the below dependency in it.
   https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections
2. download the jar file then follow these steps.

   Go to Project

   Open Module Setting

   Select the module

   Click on the (+) sign in the right side --> You will get the options to add as a jar, 
    module dependency or library

You can select whichever way is suitable for you.

here are images for your ease.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes thanks, i did it the second way. But i still get errors, but i can't tell if it comes from the library import or from the code.

Comment: Ok. If possible share the errors so that we can see if it's from the code or imports.

Comment: I get this error : `org.reflections.ReflectionsException: Scanner SubTypesScanner was not configured`

My code is pretty simple tho, i took an example somewhere.

Comment: As I can not see your code. I can suggest have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782240/java-reflections-get-classes-but-not-subtypes

Comment: I've already seen this answer and it doesn't work. This is strange. But anyway, thanks for your help.